# selenium / chronium can't solve recaptchas

Tags: selenium

When selenium (chrome with chromedriver) window is opened I can't login in a form. Even after I manually solve the captcha (I have to do a million tests), it says it's solved. I press login and bam it resets.

Outside of the selenium window it does work. Any idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, Selenium can not solve the captchas.
Also about the second part of your problem (After you log in, it resets.) I think it could be the time issue. You need to make your execution wait until you solve the captcha manually.

For example, a captcha should have one checkbox, and after you solved the captcha it should automatically be checked. You can make your execution wait until that checkbox is checked.

You can use something like this:

```
    WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();

    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

    WebElement captchaCheckBox = driver.findElement(By.xpath("the xpath location of the checkbox from captcha")); //You can use other locators too, like id or name or whatever.

    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,20);

    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeSelected(captchaCheckBox));
```

After you do that you can continue to do your other actions like clicking the log in button, navigating to the main page of your application, etc.

Also if the code above doesn't work, after you find the checkbox you can try to find the attribute of that webelement which shows whether the checkbox is checked or not. It can be something like this inside the HTML tag: aria-checked="false"

After you find that attribute in the tag of your webelement you can use this code:

```
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.attributeContains(captchaChecBox, aria-checked, "true"));
```

instead of this:

```
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeSelected(captchaCheckBox));
```

If I understood the problem correctly, this should work. I hope it helps.

Comment: I know selenium can't solve the captcha. In this case, assume selenium only opens a window. And does nothing else. Now I manually go to a random website. That's where I have to login and solve the captcha. However when I solve the captcha (manually!) and enter the login details. It just refreshed the login screen and I have to fill out the login details and captcha again. This loops.

If I just open a chrome window and I go to that page, fill out the login details and the captcha, then there is no issue. 

The problem

Comment: Could you send the code if it is ok? Also if you put your project in github open to public it would be nice to have a github link. If not it is ok.